# Conversation not propagated automatically on form submission?

Tags: java, jsf, cdi, conversation-scope

I have the following conversation scoped backing bean:

```
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class TestConversation implements Serializable {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestConversation.class);

    private List<Integer> numbers;

    @Inject
    private Conversation conversation;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        logger.info("Creating TestConversation bean!!!");

        numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        numbers.add(3);
        numbers.add(4);
        numbers.add(5);
        numbers.add(6);

        conversation.begin();        
    }

    public void commandLinkAction() {
        logger.info("Invoking commandLinkAction");
    }

    public List<Integer> getNumbers() {
        return numbers;
    }
}
```

And the following facelets view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <h:head>
        <title>Testing Conversation</title>        
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:dataTable value="#{testConversation.numbers}" var="num">
                <h:column>                    
                    <h:outputText value="#{num}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>                    
                    <h:commandLink action="#{testConversation.commandLinkAction}">Trigger form submission</h:commandLink>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

When I enter the page I see `INFO: Creating TestConversation bean!!!` which is correct.

But then I click on the `h:commandLink` and I see:

> INFO: Creating TestConversation bean!!!
>   INFO: Invoking commandLinkAction

The bean was created again, which means that the conversation was not propagated. I think this contradicts with the following:

Quote from [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/ConversationScoped.html):

> The long-running conversation context associated with a request that renders a JSF view is automatically propagated to any faces request (JSF form submission) that originates from that rendered page.

If I add this `<f:param name="cid" value="#{javax.enterprise.context.conversation.id}"/>` then everything works fine. Do I have a misunderstanding?

P.S Without the `f:param` it works fine when I click on the `commandLink` for the second time, but not on the first time:(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on the previous answer, it's definitely because the `TestConversation` bean is not being constructed until it's already too late for the form to include the `cid` automatically.

In this case, you're initializing data for the view, so it's probably better to put it in a preRenderView event listener instead.

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{testConversation.init}"/>
```

Put this early in your facelet template, such as in the `f:metadata` (as it's often used in conjunction with `f:viewParam`), and remove the `@PostConstruct` annotation. That makes the invocation of `init` explicit rather than relying on it being run as a side effect of the bean being constructed because it was referenced in an EL expression.

Comment: Thanks it works this way. But I hate that this `preRenderView` fires also for `ajax` requests. I have to check `conversation.isTransient()` in my `init` method to avoid an exception.

Answer (score 3):

I guess, the problem seems like conversation was not started when the `<h:form>` component was processed so the form's action did not had cid in it for the first time..

For the second time, when you click on a link, `testConversation.commandLinkAction`, access to `testConversation` made the conversation to start before processing the `<h:form>`

try the below change

If you place `#{testConversation}` before `<h:form>`
example works fine as converation is started before processing the `<h:form>`

Hope this helps..